# Apache Tomcat with Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat7, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

We run Apache Tomcat 7 with multiple deployed .war applications. We use Eclipselink as our ORM solution, which is installed as a library at the server level. (see below)

```
Apache Tomcat/
     lib/
        eclipselink.jar
     webapps/
        app1.war
        app2.war
        app3.war
```

However, each application has its own persistence.xml setup, we recently found that two deployed applications were some how dependent on each other. If I remove app1, then app2 the EntityManager would function differently, putting back app1 caused app1 to work. We narrowed it down to a single line in the persistence.xml was in app1 but not in app2.

```
<property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
```

It is my understanding each Apache Tomcat war application is isolated with its own classloader, thereby isolating each app.

Q. Since EclipseLink is loaded at the server level configurations is getting "shared" across the apps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What specifically is being shared? For example, the a database name, or something like the number of open connections?

Comment: Each app creates its own entitymanager, which utilizes jpa (eclipselink), the configuration is slightly different in each app, which is where I was having issues.  app1 was loading first, having configuration that was hiding errors in app2, and only when we moved app2 to its own JVM did we notice the issues.